# Would it be possible to have a Question Template for new users?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it was possible to have a question template for new users.

I was thinking of something simple, where, for example, in the first 2 sentences they have to enunciate what their issue is, and then have a full description of the problem, and possibly, at the end, have a 2 lines section with some "final remarks"?

I have seen many questions that are very long and it is hard to know what the issue the OP has.

I think it is something you learn with experience, I have done it myself, and sometimes still struggle with, but at least I am aware of.

For new users it could be useful to have a reminder of a good way to structure a question.

Do you think this would be useful? Or even possible to implement?

Comment: How would that look for users on the cooking site? Lego site? French language site? Code golfing?

Comment: Did you ever notice the guidance on the sidebar when you first load the ask question page?

Comment: I don't think we should have a template, but rather, make it easy for new users to figure out how to ask their questions.

Comment: @Oded - I think that the template could be just a suggestion, and not forced, just like greyed out text on the question textbox. Also anytime you have a question you can reduce it to few generic words.  Do you refer to the area that says "How to Ask?" "How to format?"

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI - what do you mean?

Comment: We would be clearer on what we mean when we say 'on-topic'. We could provide a 'new user question guide' in the Help Center, and it would say things like "be clear", "don't just post your errors", "remember the solution may not be what you want", etc. The only problem is that the Help Center may cover all of this already.

Comment: Dzyann, it doesn't take an SE to know how to ask a question properly, even if it's on the internet.

Comment: @MARamezani - I don't know what SE stands for. But many people struggle about what is the way to ask or write things, to have a clear hint to remind you a good way to start can be very useful. Maybe this is a better fit for Stack Overflow, I didn't post it there because I thought it was a general Q&A suggestion.

Comment: (SE == Stack Exchange)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ - I thought SE might stand for Stack Exchange, but then I don't understand Maramezani's comment at all.

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI - To say "be clear" is not clear. What is clear for me, might not for you and and the other way around. It depends on the culture, etc. Having a specific "guide" that could be helpful both for askers and bothers is what I am aiming for.

Answer (score 2):

I genuinely like your idea on face-value. If it was realistic or possible it might bring about better quality in questions overall.

However, I do not believe there is such a thing as a "general" or "average" question which would allow a *template* to be made from, or even allow basic advice to be given.

Oded mentioned different sites, and is a valid point, but not even going that far:
Even with one site - say Stack Overflow - the difference in *tags* on that one site means no one template would work, heck not even 30 templates would be of any use.

> For new users it could be useful to have a reminder of a good way to
>   structure a question.

But every question on even just the S.O. [PHP] tag has a different angle, topic, scope, code, etc, let alone across all tags. We'd have to write hundreds to cater for all tags.

If we did not cater for all tags, then the templates or advice would have to be very generic to fit in with all tags and possible question scopes. And then we're back to it being largely useless and the fact that all the info we could provide to be helpful *is already there*.

### Bad questions are bad because bad askers

Users who do not care about asking quality questions, or doing some leg work, will (for the most part) not be "fixed" by some generic template or advice even if in their face.

Even providing a template, it would be so "loose" and generic that a bad asker would still end up with a bad question - either from badly changing the template, or adding their own *still-poor* stuff around the template base.

Users can *now* read many areas of the site to learn how to write a good question. The Help Center, Meta questions, heck even viewing other well received questions in the tag they are about to ask in.

I commend your wanting to improve things, but I think you are fighting a losing battle, as those who want to write a good question have all the tools and info they need, otherwise, you cannot fight laziness or lack of care or understanding.

### Votes would be based on templates

Votes on a question would no longer be *solely* based on a user's *own* asking merits, and would also be based on the template quality (even if only "loosely").

This would likely introduce a big problem - imagine if a user used an official Stack template, or in-question advice, for their question, and it got downvotes.
How many users would *flock* to the Meta sites to complain about how their question was downvoted by Stack users when it was Stack which provided the basis of the question

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aiming to a generic template/reminder, If you can summarize a question to a short title, as everyone is forced to do here, I think you can, provide a short description of the issue in the first paragraph of a Question. As I said on one of my comments, I didn't think of a template forced unto users, but more like grayed out text on the question, which you are free to ignore.

Comment: When you sign up you are shown Tour, told of Help Center. When you ask, the question already has a greyed out prompt/advice for the title. Other than that, how far can we go to get people to read? If they did not bother with learning the site a bit, or reading Tour or Help Center or other good questions, why would they read that? As per my "Bad askers" section, I don't think it would fix anything because of the types of users who ask bad questions. If the want the help, it's already there really.

Comment: To be honest, some people tend to be verbose, while others are succinct. I think is ok to be verbose if in the first few lines you say what you are aiming to. For example, I summarized an OP question that was very long into 2 or 3 lines, he was getting downvoted, and it is not that he didnt do the effort, he just didnt know the best way to structure his question. With the edits in the end he got his answer.

Comment: A year ago I suggested a similar feature-request. It didn't get many upvotes or following. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195977/implement-placeholder-overlay-text-outlining-main-question-requirements-inside-t  - Even though I proposed the idea myself, since then, having learned more about the site, and the types of users who ask poor questions, I doubt it would help much TBH

Comment: I am a person that has a problem summarizing things, which brings a lot of issues, not only on SE. After a lot of auto coaching and forcing myself into saying things first in few lines, I do better. In most cases I had only needed a reminder to say what you want succinctly at first. It is an email writing technique advised in many places, and even when you write reports they suggest the same, the first section describes the purpose of the whole report.

Comment: In any case, having said all what I have, I agree with you, I don't think I will get much adherence. I searched before posting for a similar question and I didn't see it, thanks for the link. I really think this could really be useful for OP and users with more experience, since they will have less to review, but oh well, not everyone can agree with me :)

Comment: *Bad questions are bad because bad askers* - I strongly disagree with this. The reason we overhauled question blocks and rate limits is because _many_ people go on to ask really good questions after floundering in their first few attempts. Many people just don't realize that there _are_ such things as 'bad' questions, much less the possibility that they're about to ask one :)

Comment: @TimPost I agree that not all people who initially ask bad questions are bad *people*, some go on to ask good questions. But, they were arguably lazy (ie bad in some way at first) when they initially asked their bad questions, because all the info is already there to avoid that, including learning that a bad question even exists. I suppose I was trying to get across "how much info can we push before it's *very surplus*"? I found "How to ask a good question" pretty quickly as a new user, as well as other similar things. I'll re-read my answer and edit/make more clear at some point :)